# Замена в строке регуляркой

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь заменить в строке найденные вхождения регуляркой но не совсем получается то что нужно.

Строка вида `[STRING_****]  (STRING_*****)  /STRING`

Нужно заменить все STRING кроме /STRING при этом у меня почему то заменяются и скобки.

```
$file    = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/data.txt');

$searchContext  = 'STRING';
$replaceContext = 'NEW_STRING';

$pattern = '/([\[(\s])('.$searchContext.')/';

$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replaceContext, $file);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В оригинальном регулярном выражении заданы 2 захватывающие группы  (подмаска), каждая из которых создаёт буфер в памяти, в котором хранится часть совпадения:

```
'/([\[(\s])('.$searchContext.')/'
  | --1-- || ------ 2 ------- |
```

Содержимое этих двух групп можно "восстановить", т.е. обратиться к тексту в этих группах, с помощью [обратных ссылок](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.back-references.php), которые можно использовать в шаблоне замены, используя следующий синтаксис: `$` + `идентификатор группы`. Группа №1 — это шаблон, обрамлённый первой парой неэкранированных круглых скобок, в шаблоне замены надо использовать `$1`:

```
$result = preg_replace($pattern, "$1" . $replaceContext, $file);
                                 ^^^^
```

См. [PHP-демо](http://ideone.com/tjXR7e)

Из описанного выше следует, что вторая захватывающая группа лишняя.

Есть ещё один способ. В захватывающей группе задан шаблон известной длины (`([\[(\s])` находит один символ), поэтому можно просто преобразовать группу в блок предварительного просмотра назад и использовать

```
$pattern = '/(?<=[\[(\s])'.$searchContext.'/';
$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replaceContext, $file);
```

[Ещё одно демо](http://ideone.com/KoyFoM)

Блоки предварительного просмотра не добавляют найденный текст в конечный массив значений, а также не меняет позицию в строке (т.е. шаблон этих блоков проверяется на наличие/отстутвие, а при выходе из блока поиск последующих шаблонов продолжается с того же места в строке, где начался поиск шаблона блока).

В PCRE, кроме двух описанных способов, можно воспользоваться оператором "сброса совпадения", `\K`:

```
preg_replace('/[\[(\s]\K'.$searchContext.'/', $replaceContext, $file)
```

[И снова демо](http://ideone.com/K4iaz0)

Всё, что было найдено до `\K`, удаляется из буфера совпадения.

**Примечание**: Если в `$searchContext` ожидается наличие специальных метасимволов (операторов, таких как `(`, `)`, `[`, `{`, `\`, `+`, `^`, `$`, `*`, `?` и `.`), необходимо экранировать их с помощью `preg_quote($searchContext, '/')`. Второй параметр экранирует разделитель регулярного выражения (в данном случае, `/`).

Comment: Ухх спасибо большое,тоже не совсем понимал как вытаскивать значения из групп,теперь понял.С preg_match понимал так как там захват группы в индекс массива помещался,а тут запутался чуток

Comment: Хмм почему единственная? ('.$searchContext.') разве это не вторая группа?

Comment: @quaresma89: Язык мой — враг мой. В общем, тут надо ещё много писать, а у меня двое детей на шее, пора спать укладывать.

Comment: И на том спасибо)

Comment: @quaresma89: Если мой ответ помог Вам решить задачу, пожалуйста, [отметьте ответ как решение](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Обязательно отмечу!

Comment: Возможно не был бы лишним `preg_quote($searchContext)`

Comment: Да, руки не дошли об этом упомянуть, все время думал об этом, только надо `preg_quote($searchContext, '/')`